# How to make PostgreSQL ignore the client's timezone when getting LOCALTIMESTAMP?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

According to the documentation, PostgreSQL's function `localtimestamp` returns "current date and time" and the value is "without time zone". But I found that the returned value depends not only on the current absolute time but also on the timezone setting of the client:

```
clan_1=> SET timezone='UTC';
SET
clan_1=> SELECT localtimestamp;
       localtimestamp       
----------------------------
 2019-04-15 12:50:23.754272
(1 row)

clan_1=> SET timezone='Europe/Prague';
SET
clan_1=> SELECT localtimestamp;
       localtimestamp       
----------------------------
 2019-04-15 14:50:33.678917
(1 row)
```

In my DB functions, I need to get consistent data (of type *timestamp*, not *timestamptz*) no matter what client (and its timezone setting) is used to call them. After some research, I found that the following should work:

```
SELECT current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Is there any better (simpler) way?

---

PostgreSQL 10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way to do it is fine, but so is the simpler

```
SELECT current_timestamp;
```

It will also return the same timestamp for all sessions, only they will be formatted according to the session time zone.

That shouldn't be a problem, because `2019-04-01 12:00:00+02` is the same as `2019-04-01 10:00:00+00`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I need to get _timestamp_ (not _timestamptz_). (I admit I haven't mentioned it explicitly in my original question.)

Comment: Then your solution is the best one.